# What is the best way to keep a list of products updated from a server?(IOS)

Tags: ios, xml, sockets

I want to keep a list of products updated in IOS.What I thought of was that I would keep the list in a XML file and I would check the version of the XML on my device with the version of the XML on the server and if it's not the latest version I would download the latest version but that is not the most convenient way.And should i use socket programming or is there a better option?I have tried socket programming before so I'm familiar with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Approach 1, you could save the current version using [Core Data](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/cdProgrammingGuide.html) which is fast to retrieve and define a RESTful interface on the server for the client to inquire what's the newest which is light weight. And then when certain View Controller life cycle event happens, ask the server if there is any update. But never write a infinite loop to keep sending request to server.

Approach 2, you may utilize the [Push Notifications](https://developer.apple.com/notifications/) to notification there is update available, this is more power saving on the client side but it's more complicated to set it up.

Comment: Thank you very much ! this will help a lot.